# Where to store PWA app data on OneDrive not to be accessible by user?

Tags: onedrive, progressive-web-apps, appdata

I want to write a PWA app (to run on Android and Windows 10) working with user's files and photos on OneDrive. I need to store some metadata and I prefer those to be inaccessible to the user.

What are my options?

- OneDrive [`approot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#roaming-data) special folder is normal folder visible to the user.
- I do not want to store the data locally on the device, as I want the app to be run on multiple devices.
- I cannot use Windows 10 UWP [roaming app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#roaming-data), as they would sync between Windows 10 devices, but not to Android devices.
- I do not want to store the data at the PWA's backend, as it would need creating an extra user account. I want the user to log in to their MS Account to access their OneDrive, and to create another account for storing metadata. I prefer the app to be 100% client side.

Are there any other options I missed? I would prefer creating some hidden folder on OneDrive accessible by the app, but by the user. OneDrive does not seem to have such functionality, at least if I read it's API docs properly.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your exact use case you may want to check out Microsoft Graph:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph

Microsoft Graph is an cross-device experiences platform and available for nearly all platforms. Within the Microsoft Graph you can use Activities to share metadata between different devices: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/resources/project_rome_overview.md

There is also an demo project on Github of an PWA with usage of the Microsoft Graph:
https://github.com/boyofgreen/MSGraphPWA

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mention in my question I am aware of MS Graph and intend to use it. However Activities does not seem to help me, as they represent user's engagement with the app's entities. I need to store static metadata about users files and photos (but not per file, so extensions is not an option either). My question was where to store them.